# loading an image from resources folder using relative path

Tags: java, swt

How to set the images in background of shell using relative path. I have image which resides in folder "res". I am adding screen shot here, just you to have better understanding of 'directory structure' as well as my question(in case if it seemed little ambiguous to you). Any suggestion and help will be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `SplashWindow.jpg` is placed next to the class `notDltNow` which you specify as the reference for relative paths, so you can simply write:

```
shell.setBackgroundImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(
    notDltNow.class, "SplashWindow.jpg"));
```

It is also a good idea to put resources inside the `src` folder so when you export your code e.g. into a jar, the resources will also be exported and still available to the code without additional hassle.

Comment: I know that way of doing it. could u please tell me how to load image from "res" folder which is out of src.

Comment: The way you load the image `SWTResourceManager.getImage(Class,String)` uses `Class.getResourceAsStream()` so the image must be placed in the same place the class is loaded from. You must put the image inside the src folder, or load the image in a different way.

Comment: without making use of SWTResourceManager,is there any way to accomplish my objective ? will Image class help ?

Comment: `SWTResourceManager.getImage()` has multiple forms / overloads. There is a version which takes the image path as a string. You can pass `"res/SpashWindow.jpg"` to it assuming the current folder is the project root when you run the application from Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

In order to read your images from `resources` folder, you need to :

> add res folder to classpath
>
> locate file absolutely, i.e. "/res/SplashWindow.jpg"

Hope this helps